# Flex Builder 3 and Flash Builder compatibility

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Hi
I use Flex Builder 3 for all my coding. Recently, at the office where I work we are upgrading to Flash Builder.
I would still like to work on the same projects at home using Flex Builder.

Can anyone tell me what compatibility issues I will run into?

Is it impossible to share the same project between Flash Builder and Flex Builder?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar setup. I haven't really encountered any problems. Just make sure you're using the same SDK. I typically work with Actionscript projects as opposed to Flex projects, so I'm not sure if there would be any issues there. I have had issues with going from Flex 3 to FDT, but that was mainly due to the project files and compiling method. As a solution, I usually place my source, library and bin files in source control (svn or git) and ignore the project files. Then, set up separate projects in each environment.

Comment: thanks! Have to remember to ignore the .project files or I'm sure I WILL have issues.